# How to inform users that api maintenance is in progress

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using azure app service and DB for my C# ODATA API and DB as the backend of of my phone app.
I only have one app service that hosts 10s of endpoints. There are times when I need to publish new versions and I don't want any incoming requests during that time of deployment.

I don't mind that users are not able to finish their requests during the maintenance.

Is there anything in Azure or API that can let me:
1. turn off the api/app service manually? 
2. Be able to inform the user that a maintenance is in progress?

This is my trial:
the only thing I can come up with is this. While users always use the "odata" in their url requests:  https://myserverl/odata/Users

which is setup in the webapi.config like this:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

I put the routePrefix (2nd odata) in a web.config. 
When I need to turn off access, I change my web.config (which I can access manually even after the publish of code into Azure) to be like this:

```
<add key="odata" value="noaccess" />
```

and in my webapi.config:

```
string odata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["odata"].ToString();
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", odata, builder.GetEdmModel());
```

and then save the web.config which will reset the server and all incoming requests that has "odata" will result into error. I can always set it back later.

This method will stop the users from sending requests during maintenance but will not let them know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
when I call the server from my client, I verify that the response is between 200 & 299 before parsing results or any other further processing. 
So now, I check also for the possible response from the server that it could be either 403 (access is denied) or 503 (server is unavailable). That's where I can add code to notify the user.

In Azure, simply stopping the app service, will generate one of those 2 error codes.

Note: You must check for both: 403 & 503.